# Selecting current valid record of historical Data with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables

Table Customer

- customer_shortcut (char)

Table CustomerData

- customerID (ForeignKey to Customer)
- customer_valid (Valid date for the record)
- customer_name (char)

Table CustomerData can have multiple records for a customer, but with different valid dates, p.e.

```
01.01.2019
01.01.2020
01.01.2021
```

I managed to get the last record for each customer using the query:

```
SELECT Customer.*
FROM Customer
    FULL JOIN CustomerData ON (Customer.id = CustomerData."customerID_id")
    FULL JOIN CustomerData CustomerData2 ON (Customer.id = CustomerData2."customerID_id" 
        AND (CustomerData.customer_valid < CustomerData2.customer_valid 
             OR CustomerData.customer_valid = CustomerData2.customer_valid 
             AND CustomerData.id < CustomerData2.id)
            )
WHERE CustomerData2.id IS NULL
```

How do I get now the current valid record (in my example the record with customer_valid 01.01.2020)?

I tried to add "AND customer_valid <= '2020-05-05' on nearly every position within the query but never got the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for the highest "valid date" that is before "today" (or any given date). This can be achieved using a lateral join in Postgres:

```
SELECT c.*, cd.customer_name
FROM customer c
  JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT * 
    FROM customerdata cd 
    WHERE c.id = cd.customer_id
      AND cd.customer_valid <= current_date
    ORDER BY cd.customer_valid DESC 
    LIMIT 1
  ) cd on true
```

---

A more efficient option would be (in my opinion) to store the start and the end of the valid period in a [`daterange` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html):

```
create table customer_data
(
  customer_id    int not null references customer, 
  valid_during   daterange not null,
  customer_name  text
);
```

Overlapping ranges can be prevented using an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT)

And the example ranges from your question would be stored as

```
[2019-01-01,2020-01-01)
[2020-01-01,2021-01-01)
[2021-01-01,infinity)
```

The `)` denotes that the right edge is excluded.

The query then becomes as simple as:

```
SELECT c.*, cd.customer_name
FROM customer c
  JOIN customer_data cd 
    on c.id = cd.customer_id
   AND cd.valid_during @> current_date;
```